# Can '=' be used to set one object property given a different unique key:value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

If I know an object exists in an array with a unique key:value pair do I have use .find() to get the object or is there a way that doesn't require iteration?

Given:

```
const testObj = [
{id: '001', first: 'fThing1', other: [{id: '001.1'}, {id: '001.2'}], arr: ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'] },
{id: '002', first: 'fThing2', other: [{id: '002.1'}, {id: '002.2'}], arr: ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'] },
{id: '003', first: 'fThing3', other: [{id: '003.1'}, {id: '003.2'}], arr: ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'] }
]
```

Is there a notation to do:

```
testObj.id['001'](some notation)first = 'something'
```

Or do I have to do:

```
temp = testObj.find(to => to.id === '001')
temp.first = 'something'
```

Comment: You need to `find()` it as in your last example. (unless you already know the index in which case `testObj[0].first = 'something'`)

Comment: You can use `Map` here to transform it and then can find it and perform some operation

Comment: If it's an array, there's no way to iterate it; one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question...

> Is there a notation to do

The answer is *"no"*.

If your elements have unique IDs, considering collecting them into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) keyed by `id` if you need that sort of access...

```js
const testObj = [{"id":"001","first":"fThing1","other":[{"id":"001.1"},{"id":"001.2"}],"arr":["a1","b1","c1"]},{"id":"002","first":"fThing2","other":[{"id":"002.1"},{"id":"002.2"}],"arr":["a2","b2","c2"]},{"id":"003","first":"fThing3","other":[{"id":"003.1"},{"id":"003.2"}],"arr":["a3","b3","c3"]}]

const idMap = new Map(testObj.map(o => [o.id, o]))

// word of warning, this will error if the ID doesn't exist
idMap.get("001").first = "something"

console.log(testObj[0])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Because the object references in `testObj` and the `Map` are the same, any changes to one will be reflected in the other.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) mentioned, the notation you asked about is not possible.

Another option is to use function `.map()` to return a new array with updated objects:

```js
const testObj = [
  {id: '001', first: 'fThing1', other: [{id: '001.1'}, {id: '001.2'}], arr: ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'] },
  {id: '002', first: 'fThing2', other: [{id: '002.1'}, {id: '002.2'}], arr: ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'] },
  {id: '003', first: 'fThing3', other: [{id: '003.1'}, {id: '003.2'}], arr: ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'] }
];

const result = testObj.map(item =>
  item.id === '001' ? {
    ...item,
    first: 'something'
  } : item
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was thinking it would be efficient to not have to iterate over the array of objects, so I was looking for a way to directly address known objects. This is a safe way of iterating though, so useful...

Comment: As a general rule, I prefer iteration if the array is small. If the array is large (eg thousands of items) I'd be concerned about performance and might consider another way.